# Get first and last date of a month given any date

Tags: sql, date, oracle11g

I have a date in oracle in yyyy-mm-dd format. Is it possible to get from this the following:
1.The exact date 1 yr ago in yyyy-mm-dd format (so : 2013-02-01--> 2012-02-01 and  2013-02-28--> 2012-02-29)
2.The corresponding start date and end date of the same month in yyyy-mm-dd format

Comment: Why is "the exact date 1 year ago" from Feb 1, 2013 Feb 29, 2012?  That's more like 11 months and 1 day ago.  What is your definition of "exactly 1 year ago"?  What is 1 year prior to Feb 29 in a leap year?  Feb 28 in the prior year?  March 1 in the prior year?  An error?  Something else?

Comment: Don't you mean 2013-03-01 --> 2012-02-29 rather than 2013-03-01--> 2012-02-29?  Even that doesn't make much sense, at I would think 2013-03-01 --> 2012-03-01 would make sense.  The only problem is 2012-02-29 --> 2011-02-28 ??

Comment: Thanks. Sorry about that, i corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT
  TRUNC(DATE '2013-02-01', 'MM') - INTERVAL '1' YEAR AS one_year_ago_first_day,
  LAST_DAY(TRUNC(DATE '2013-02-28', 'MM') - INTERVAL '1' YEAR) AS one_year_ago_last_day,
  TRUNC(DATE '2013-02-11', 'MM'),
  LAST_DAY(DATE '2013-02-11')
FROM
  dual;
```

Basically, you can get the first day of a month by using `TRUNC` with `MM` model format, so everything after month will be truncated (so day will be set to 1).

`LAST_DAY` - this one returns the date of the last day in the month of the date given as a parameter.

You can also use `INTERVAL` datatype and subtract it from given date.